# How do I open a tab of google maps in unity without buying an Asset?

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble figuring out how do I open a tab of google maps or google maps app on my app within the unity, and can't afford to buy the Asset for facilitating, what do I do? is there any other site or application that I can use and be easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use [AndroidJavaClass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html) and [AndroidJavaObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.html) API to construct common map intents: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

There are plenty examples out there how to use AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject e.g. how to create a share intent. These are very similar for maps.